# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object error from IMGUR API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, imgur

I am trying to get all the images from an imgur album. It works fine with all of the albums, except when i try to get images from 
[this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQu4T.jpg)

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Imgur.API.Models.Impl.Image]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Here is my code, which throws out the exception.

```
public async Task<List<IImage>> dosomething()
{
    IEnumerable<IImage> image = await Task.Run(AccessTheWebAsync);
    return image.ToList(); ;
}
async Task<IEnumerable<IImage>> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
    var client = new ImgurClient(token);
    var endpoint = new AlbumEndpoint(client);
    IEnumerable<IImage> images = await endpoint.GetAlbumImagesAsync(albumlink);
    return images;
}
```

Comment: Where is your deserialization?

Comment: @Mahdi Well, there is none on my end, i just turn it into a list. It works with all of the albums except this one. Should i look into it?

Comment: It looks like you're using a 3rd party library to obscure away the serialisation for you. Can you specify which library you're referencing to connect to the Imgur API?

Comment: @Equalsk https://github.com/DamienDennehy/Imgur.API this one.

Comment: What is the value of `albumlink`?

Comment: @Equalsk Dc2k6#0

Comment: It shouldn't have the `#0` on the end, try `Dc2k6`.

Comment: @Equalsk Please put that as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `albumlink` that you're passing is incorrect, it should not have the `#0` on the end.

The value for `albumlink` should just be `Dc2k6`.

I'm not sure why the `#0` is there, I assume it can select a specific image or something but I couldn't get it to work. To prove it's irrelevant, add any other value after the `#`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9pQ6.jpg